# What defines the qualitative and quantitative characteristics of a dataset?

Tags: dataset

Can somebody tell the differences between quantitative and qualitative characteristics of a dataset?

After reading multiple articles on the subject, with different explanations, I am a bit confused.

Comment: Qualitative refers to reliability, accuracy and data quality. Quantitative represents the amount of data.

Comment: I need to understand what you mean by data set? Is this a geodatabase? Is it a file dataset, for example in * .shp format? Or is this the data about the objects that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Do you mean a data set in vector or raster form?

Answer (score 0):

The qualitative and quantitative characteristics of a data set determine the properties and indicators of the data.

For example, the object of the map 'Bridge' has quantitative characteristics: Length - '150 m', Width - '20 m', Height above water level - '10 m', and the quality characteristics of the building material - 'reinforced concrete' and etc. as a result, the quantitative characteristics are properties of an object expressed in numerical values, and qualitative characteristics are properties of an object expressed in text form ...

If we are talking about a data set, then I can assume that the quantitative characteristics are measured in bytes, for example, the data volume is 12 MB, and the qualitative characteristics of the data set can be the following - full data, or not full data, accurate or rough, reliable or unreliable etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a clear explanation.